# Raising ValidationError when it comes to custom validation

Tags: python, django, forms

i have problem with showing an error in form.

Let say, that my form has 2 fields, which are not require only if they are both empty, but we cannot let to situation when only one has a value.
So i tried to do this validation in view and then raise an exception, and everything is okay, BUT Error is raised as debug page with traceback etc.

```
raise utils.ValidationError(u'SOME EXAMPLE TEXT')
```

This was in view.

So I tried other way, i've readed that i can do validation in def clean in form

## IN FORM

```
def clean(self):
    super(forms.Form,self).clean()
    if 'departure_date_time_plain' in self.cleaned_data and 'arrival_date_time_plain' not in self.cleaned_data:
        self._errors['arrival_date_time_plain'] = [u'PUT HERE SOME DATE']

    if 'departure_date_time_plain' not in self.cleaned_data and 'arrival_date_time_plain' in self.cleaned_data:
        self._errors['arrival_date_time_plain'] = [u'PUT HERE SOME DATE']
    return self.cleaned_data
```

## VIEW My view code for second approach:

```
def new_bus(request, id, id_sec):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        train_form = TrainForm(request.POST)
        args['new_train'] = train_form
        if "train" in request.POST and train_form.is_valid():
            if train_form['reservation_train'].value():
                 train = Train.objects.create(                  
                    transportation=train_form['trans'].value(),
                    number=train_form['num'].value(),                                    
                    departure=train_form['departure_date_time_train'].value(),
                    arrival=train_form['arrival_date_time_train'].value(),
                    reservation=train_form['reservation_train'].value(),
                    seat_number=train_form['seat_number_train'].value(),
                    section_numbers=train_form['section_numbers_train'].value()
                    )
            else:
                 train = Train.objects.create(reservation=False)

           sec = Section.objects.get(id=id_sec)
           sec.locomotion = JourneyType.objects.create(train=train)
           sec.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/trip/'+ id)
    args['new_train'] = TrainForm()
    return render(request, 'add_trip/new_bus.html', args)
```

And this method don't ever were called, could you tell my how to resolve this problem ? Because i run out of tutorials, and any other options, or maybe i just missed something. I would be grateful for any answer

-- ANSWER --

Thanks for comments from @Shang Wang i found out what was really a problem. Clean is going to call only when your field is `requierd=True`, and my errors wasn't correctly showing because of one mistake:

Instead of :

```
bus_form = BusForm(request.POST)
plain_form = PlainForm(request.POST)
train_form = TrainForm(request.POST)
args['new_bus'] = bus_form
args['new_plain'] = plain_form
args['new_train'] = train_form
```

I had:

```
bus_form = BusForm()
plain_form = PlainForm()
train_form = TrainForm()
args['new_bus'] = bus_form
args['new_plain'] = plain_form
args['new_train'] = train_form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem for your second approach is that you didn't captured the `cleaned_data` that is returned from parent `clean` method. Also you were calling the wrong `super` method. `super` should be called on the form class itself, not the class that current class is inherited from. I think you should:

```
class CurrentForm(forms.Form):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CurrentForm, self).clean()
        if 'departure_date_time_plain' in cleaned_data and 'arrival_date_time_plain' not in cleaned_data:
            self._errors['arrival_date_time_plain'] = [u'PUT HERE SOME DATE']

        if 'departure_date_time_plain' not in cleaned_data and 'arrival_date_time_plain' in cleaned_data:
            self._errors['arrival_date_time_plain'] = [u'PUT HERE SOME DATE']
        return self.cleaned_data
```

[You will always have the best tutorial by checking out django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Unfortunately i doesn't helped, this still wasn't event called. Like it doesn't exist.

Comment: `train_form.is_valid()` in the views.py would call the `clean` method in your form. Can you make sure that `is_valid` is executed?

Comment: is_valid is executed. In debug it steps into is_valid and then in errors() it doesn't steps into if to call self.full_clean(). _errors is not None, but it has len 0.

Comment: It means you have other errors that django already captured by default before reaching `clean` method. Can you add an `else` branch for the `if is_valid()` and see what's the content for `train_form.errors`?

Comment: _errors is not None, but it has len 0. There is nothing. http://imgur.com/cVoQF2g

Comment: Hmm, if you just `print train_form.errors` in the `else`, nothing shows up?

Comment: Sorry kind of running out of ideas. What's in your `request.POST`?

Comment: Did you forget to fill out any required field? Does the `DateField` have the correct format? I don't have access to your environment and there are so many ways that could go wrong.

Comment: Okay so problem could be if any of my fields in form is required=True? I let my users to send empty form if they don't check reservation.